# Hyperledger composer-playground behind a firewall

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to use Hyperledger composer-playground from behind a firewall.  I can start the playground, but when I try to define a business network, it is unable to access the business network templates.  I'm assuming this is because node isn't using my company's proxy.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables works.